# PSP class import + MySQL connect

Tags: python, mysql, class, python-server-pages

Ok so im trying to import a class i made which connects to a MySQL database the class code is shown below:

```
class connection
    def__init__( self ):
        self.cnx = MySQLdb.connect(user='xxx',host='xxx',passwd='xxx',db='xxx')
```

All of the parameters for the mysql connection are correct and file containg the class is in the same directory as the PSP file. The class file is called cnx_class.py

when i run my PSP file i get 'cnx' isnt defined. My psp code is below:

```
<psp:file>
import cnx_class
</psp:file>
<%
cur = cnx.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from protein;')
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    req.write`(row)`
#end
%>
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

You are horribly, horribly confused as to how modules and classes work. Please read and work through at least the [modules section](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) and the [classes section](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html) of the Python tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
cur = cnx.cursor()
```

with

```
con=cnx_class.connection()
cur=con.cnx.cursor()
```

You can also replace

```
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
```

with

```
for row in cur.fetchall():
```

since cursors are iterators.